# IOS : View height is getting reduced when performing animation

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have the following code for moving the view up and down when keyboard appears on a text field.

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    NSLog(@"height before animation%f",self.view.frame.size.height);
    NSLog(@"%f",self.view.frame.size.height);
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,-216,320,460)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,460)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    NSLog(@"height after animation %f",self.view.frame.size.height);
    }
```

Here's a sample log I get when keyboard appears and then editing is finished :

```
2014-01-21 11:00:51.194 Master-view[456:70b] height before animation 568.000000
2014-01-21 11:00:53.635 Master-view[456:70b] height after animation 460.000000
```

The height of the view seems to get reduced which is making bottom part of the screen non-interactable. Why is this happening ?

View is moving up and is coming down too without issue. Also visually there appears to be no difference. All elements which were there before moving up are there after coming down. But the elements at bottom of the screen ( beyond the height of 460.0) are not intractable.

Comment: view moving up?? or its not working?

Comment: view is moving up and is coming down too without issue. also visually there appears to be no difference. All elements which were there before moving up are there after coming down. But the elements at bottom of the screen ( beyond the height of 460.0) are not interactable.

Comment: hey you are changing the view height check there

Comment: You are setting the view height after editing to 460 and it says the view height is 460 after the animation. Do you mean to set it back to 568?

Comment: are you running in iphone 5??

Comment: Hey thanks @kamaleshkumaryadav and Paul . That was the problem , sorry I missed it . Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 -(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
NSLog(@"height before animation%f",self.view.frame.size.height);
NSLog(@"%f",self.view.frame.size.height);
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
[self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,-216,320,self.view.frame.size.height)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

}

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
[self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,self.view.frame.size.height)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
NSLog(@"height after animation %f",self.view.frame.size.height);
}
```

I set the frame as per view height you only change the y position when key beginediting and try to set it back when end editing
may this help you

Answer (score 0):

Try changing like

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    NSLog(@"height before animation%f",self.view.frame.size.height);
    NSLog(@"%f",self.view.frame.size.height);
    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
    viewFrame.origin.y = -216;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    [self.view setFrame:viewFrame];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

     CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
     viewFrame.origin.y = 0;
     [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
     [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
     [self.view setFrame:viewFrame];
     [UIView commitAnimations];
     NSLog(@"height after animation %f",self.view.frame.size.height);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We use NSNotification keyboard will show and keyboard will hide for that.

**we use add notification  for keyboard  show and hide we add in viewWillAppear a notification and remove Notification in viewWillDisappear.**

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{**
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                               object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated**
{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                                  object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                                  object:nil];
}


-(void)keyboardWillShow {

    if (self.view.frame.origin.y >= 0)
    {
        [self setViewMovedUp:YES];
    }
    else if (self.view.frame.origin.y < 0)
    {
        [self setViewMovedUp:NO];
    }
}

-(void)keyboardWillHide {
    if (self.view.frame.origin.y >= 0)
    {
        [self setViewMovedUp:YES];
    }
    else if (self.view.frame.origin.y < 0)
    {
        [self setViewMovedUp:NO];
    }
}



-(void)setViewMovedUp:(BOOL)movedUp
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3]; 

    CGRect rect = self.view.frame;
    if (movedUp)
    {

        rect.origin.y -= kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
        rect.size.height += kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
    }
    else
    {
        rect.origin.y += kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
        rect.size.height -= kOFFSET_FOR_KEYBOARD;
    }
    self.view.frame = rect;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```